# Cart products dissapear on refresh page Prestashop

Tags: shopping-cart, cart, prestashop, product

since some weeks I have a problem with my Prestashop 1.4.0.12

When I add a product to cart, ajax works correctly and add the product very well.

But, if I change page, or sometimes adding a product, the cart change deleting all products on refresh a new page.

Sometimes I can move within some pages, but dissapears the products of the cart and later if I have a new cart returns to the old cart.

Anybody knows about it? I think that the problem is on id_guest but I need to know if anyone have some solution

Thanks!

Comment: Did you make some modification to the file ajax-cart.js ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is on Domain Name, that site have 3 domains, and there are a function on Tools class that I comment because it saves on Cache some data that displays sometimes ".com" link when you are on ".org" site.

For example:

You enter on your site www.blablabla.com, and smarty caught all data and saves into server. But this web also have www.blablabla.org, if you enter you can put products on cart and visit pages (with .org on domain name) but when you enter in a product category, smarty links to ".com" site, and the Cookie where you have the product cart info dissappears because regenerate a new cookie.

Sorry for my bad english... I hope you have understood :P

Comment: what have you modified precisely?