# Ajax Cart empty Prestashop 1.6

Tags: ajax, cart, prestashop-1.6

- In prestashop 1.6
- Using Ajax-cart

If i log-in as a Customer and add products to the cart and checkout the order all work.

**Then** the ajax cart stop working.

- If I add a product to the cart and refresh the page the cart return
  empty.
- If i add a product to the cart and click "go to cart" the cart return empty.

**If i log out and log in again**, the cart **return working** for an order, then if i checkout the new order the problem return.

**seem to be a problem whith Cookie the is overwritter in some ajax call** in ajax-cart.js

I've look this but is not my case :[Cart products dissapear on refresh page Prestashop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10733051/cart-products-dissapear-on-refresh-page-prestashop)

**If i disable ajax cart all work fine.**

**EDIT**

On Google i've found something and seem to be an ajax problem but all the solution suggested don't work.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue. You should try the following module and try last two options from the module's configuration and this issue will be gone:

https://github.com/PrestaShop/pscleaner

IMPORTANT: If you are trying it on live site make sure you do not enable first options in this module i.e. Clean up Customers, Clean up Catalog & Orders.

Reply back if you still face the issue.

Cheers!!

Comment: You seems to be correct. We also tested the website in subject on multiple systems and found that the issue is still there but the frequency is quite low. I am working on it further and planning to go with the fresh setup since the issue is not traceable so far.